# How can i move/group specific folders in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, move, cut

I have a folder structure like the following:

```
2020-123-1
2020-123-2
2020-123-3
2020-124-1
2020-124-2
...
```

I need to create folders from the first 2 numbers and omit whatever follows the second dash (-). Then I need to put the prior folders under the newly created ones with the correct name.

```
2020-123
        ->2020-123-1
        ->2020-123-2
        ->2020-123-3
2020-124
        ->2020-124-1
        ->2020-124-2
```

I tried to write a script in bash like this:

```
ls -d */ > folder.txt
cut -f1,2 -d"-" folder.txt |cut -f1 -d"/" |sort|uniq  > mainfolder.txt
while read line; do mkdir $line ; done < mainfolder.txt 
while read line; do mv $(cut -f1,2 -d"-" $line) $line/ ; done < folder.txt
```

I couldn't make the last line work, I know it has issues.

Comment: I'm reading your codes, it seems that the structure is stored in a text file?

Comment: yes i send the folder names to a text file and then create folder names first. but if you believe it is unnecessary, i am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to parse the directory names and build the hierarchy. You can make use of the `-p` option of `mkdir`, thus, an awk one-liner will do the job:

```
awk -F'-' '{top=$1 FS $2;printf "mkdir -p %s; mv %s %s\n",top, $0, top}' dir.txt
```

The output with your example:

```
mkdir -p 2020-123; mv 2020-123-1 2020-123
mkdir -p 2020-123; mv 2020-123-2 2020-123
mkdir -p 2020-123; mv 2020-123-3 2020-123
mkdir -p 2020-124; mv 2020-124-1 2020-124
mkdir -p 2020-124; mv 2020-124-2 2020-124
```

### Note

- This one-liner just print the commands without executing them, you just pipe the output to `|sh` if everything looks fine. Examine the output commands, change the `printf` format/values for adjustment.
- I didn't quote the filenames, since your example doesn't contain any special chars. Do it if it is in the case.

Comment: @KaanGunduz it shouldn't if you don't use an alias. but `mv` has an `-t` option, you can add it in the command.

Comment: Thank you mate. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the final script is as follows:

```
ls -d */ | cut -f1 -d"/" > folder.txt
awk -F'-' '{top=$1 FS $2;printf "mkdir -p %s; mv %s %s\n",top, $0, top}' folder.txt |sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

for src in *-*-*; do
    destdir=${src%-*}
    [[ -d $destdir ]] || mkdir "$destdir" || exit
    # This just prints out the command that will be called.
    # Remove the "echo" in actual script after making sure it will run as intented
    echo mv "$src" "$destdir"
done
```

In the script above it is assumed that each file name to be moved contains exactly two dashes. If it can contain two *or more* dashes then the `destdir=${src%-*}` line should be replaced with these two lines:

```
suffix=${src#*-*-}
destdir=${src%"-$suffix"}
```

For detailed information read the ["shell parameter expansion" section in bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Additionally, a good read article is: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)